Question 11 from chapter 3 of Sheldon Ross book A First course to probability 10th ed.
Two cards are randomly chosen without replacement from an ordinary deck of 52 cards. Let B be the event that both cards are aces, let $A_s$ be the event that the ace of spades is chosen, and let A be the event that at least one ace is chosen. Find $P(B|A_s)$ and $P(B|A)$?
My issue is with the first one
My Approach
$$ P(B|A_s) = \frac{P(BA_s)}{P(A_s)}
$$
$P(A_s) = \frac{1}{52}$
As set of B will contain 6 combinations of 2 ace selected from 4 aces. So $B\cap A_s$ will contain 3 combination of aces.
$P(BA_s) = \frac{3}{\binom{52}{2}}$
$P(B|A_s) = \frac{2}{17}$
Answer in book$P(B|A_s) = \frac{1}{17}$
I know this question is already in exchange but that doesn't solved my query. Thank You

The mistake is in your calculation of $P(A_s)$. You forgot that the ace of spades can be picked on either turn, so
$$P(A_s)=\frac1{52}+\frac {51}{52}\cdot\frac1{51}=\frac1{26}.$$
